# Raspberry Pi Pico doesn't respond on object creation

Tags: c, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

Making a driver for the Raspberry Pi Pico and BME280 humidity sensor I am using the MicroPython C API. I compiled into a UF2 file and my module shows up when I list with `help('modules')`. When I import my module, the class with driver code shows up in `dir(mymodule)` but when I try to create an object the terminal connected to the Raspberry Pi Pico doesn't respond:

```
typedef struct {
    mp_obj_base_t base;
    uint8_t sda;
    uint8_t scl;
    uint8_t i2c_address;
} BME280_obj_t;

const mp_obj_type_t BME280_class_type;

STATIC mp_obj_t BME280_make_new(const mp_obj_type_t *type, size_t n_args, size_t n_kw, const mp_obj_t *args) {
    mp_arg_check_num(n_args, n_kw, 2, 2, true);
    BME280_obj_t* self = m_new_obj(BME280_obj_t);
    self->base.type = &BME280_class_type;
    self->sda = mp_obj_get_int(args[0]);
    self->scl = mp_obj_get_int(args[1]);
    self->i2c_address = n_args <= 2? BME280_I2C_ADDR_SEC : mp_obj_get_int(args[2]);
    return MP_OBJ_FROM_PTR(self);
}

STATIC const mp_rom_map_elem_t BME280_locals_dict_table[] = {
    // for testing purpose i removed all methods from the class
};

STATIC MP_DEFINE_CONST_DICT(BME280_locals_dict, BME280_locals_dict_table);

const mp_obj_type_t BME280_type = {
    { &mp_type_type },
    .name = MP_QSTR_BME280,
    .print = BME280_print,
    .make_new = BME280_make_new,
    .locals_dict = (mp_obj_dict_t*) &BME280_locals_dict,
};

STATIC const mp_rom_map_elem_t bme280_module_globals_table[] = {
    { MP_ROM_QSTR(MP_QSTR___name__), MP_ROM_QSTR(MP_QSTR_bme280) },
    { MP_OBJ_NEW_QSTR(MP_QSTR_BME280), (mp_obj_t)&BME280_class_type }
};

STATIC MP_DEFINE_CONST_DICT(bme280_module_globals, bme280_module_globals_table);

// module registration
const mp_obj_module_t bme280_user_cmodule = {
    .base = { &mp_type_module },
    .globals = (mp_obj_dict_t*)&bme280_module_globals,
};

MP_REGISTER_MODULE(MP_QSTR_melopero_bme280, melopero_bme280_user_cmodule, 1);
```

I think the problem is in the initialization procedure since it does not go further.

Comment: Can you build and run the sample module? https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/develop/library.html#

Comment: @Leonardo Do not include solution to question please (post a separate answer instead).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `.print` defined but it doesn't exist in your code.

```
const mp_obj_type_t BME280_type = {
    { &mp_type_type },
    .name = MP_QSTR_BME280,
    .print = BME280_print,
    .make_new = BME280_make_new,
    .locals_dict = (mp_obj_dict_t*) &BME280_locals_dict,
};
```

There is an example of writing a proper class `print` function [here](https://micropython-usermod.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usermods_09.html)

However, this should be enough to at least satisfy the print requirement. Paste this into your code and see if it stops hanging.

```
STATIC void BME280_print(const mp_print_t *print, mp_obj_t self_in, mp_print_kind_t kind) {
    (void)kind;
    BME280_obj_t *self = MP_OBJ_TO_PTR(self_in);
    mp_print_str(print, "BME280");
}
```

Also, I'm sure you just left this out of your example, otherwise you wouldn't have been able to build it, at all, but for the sake of being thorough ~ you have to include the proper header files.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "py/runtime.h"
#include "py/obj.h"
```

Edit: I was curious. You said you got everything to build, but it hangs. I commented out the `print` function for one of my C MODULE classes, and it would not build. This tells me that you (like the header) decided to just leave this part out of your example. This wastes time. How can you be helped if your example is creating errors that do not exist for you? However, even though this answer is now wrong, I am going to leave it up as an example of why answer-seekers shouldn't pick and choose what to post. Just post ALL of the relevant script to your problem and let us figure out the rest. I'd probably have an answer for you if I wasn't solving the wrong problem. Actually, I do see your problem, you're creating your module with mixed namespaces.

Comment: Hi thank you very much for your time and answer! I think that sometimes it is better to not copy and paste whole files full of code that has nothing to do with the problem. In this case I stripped too much out sorry for this. Anyway the problem was inside the code that I posted this time: I used different names for the class type in the declaration: ```BME280_class_type``` and ```BME280_type```. Thank you again!